# Для чего необходимо apt-get -t?

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

Есть у меня, например `/etc/apt/sources.list`, и я как бы могу в нём прописать репу для jessie-backports, но можно, например, сделать `nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list` и здесь прописать репу, затем сделать `apt-get update` и далее:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install <...>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, для каких целей вообще создавать `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list`, если можно прописать в `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Например, чтобы не обновлять пакеты для jessie-backports при общем обновлении других пакетов.

Comment: ааа, понятно. Я просто пытался поставить ядро 4.9, но не получилось) Зависимости какие-то, если соглашусь снести тулзу, удалит всё(( Щас пойду разбираться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы спрашиваете две разные вещи считая что они связаны между собой, но это не так.

Где указывать репозиторий: в `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` или `/etc/apt/sources.list` - не имеет значения, добавляйте там где лично вам удобнее. Они все читаются одним списком.

Флаг `-t` не имеет отношения к тому, где указаны репозитории, этот флаг переопределяет настройки `/etc/apt/preferences` и `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`.

> This option controls the default input to the policy engine; it
>    creates a default pin at priority 990 using the specified release
>    string. This overrides the general settings in /etc/apt/preferences.

Настройки [`preferences`](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) отвечают за то, какой пакет желательно использовать, если по такому имени пакет есть в разных репозиториях.

Comment: **BCC also requires kernel version 4.1 or above. Those kernels are available in the jessie-backports repository. To add the jessie-backports repository to your system create the file ``/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list`` with the following contents:** и далее написано **``apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-base linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64``**

Comment: Всё, я понял, спасибо большое!